# Saving maintenance plan failed- invalid class string error- SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

I have the following error when trying to save a maintenance plan, everything goes well until the saving step:

> Saving maintenance plan failed.
>
> Invalid class string
>
> Program Location:
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.SaveToSqlServerAs(Package package, IDTSEvents events, String packagePath, String serverName, String serverUserName, String serverPassword)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DatabaseMaintenance.MaintenancePlan.Save()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.MaintenancePlanWizard.MaintenancePlanWizardForm.PerformActions()

I've installed SSIS but no difference. Please help.